# I want to display UPDOWN message of interface on Nexus

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

The unit exam of Nexus is underway.

Like Catalyst or IOS

"* Oct 6 08:29:28:% LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet 1/2, changed state to up"

I thought I would get an UPDOWN message for an interface like this, but it is not displayed.

Is there any way to display UPDOWN message of interface other than show command? Or is it usually displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
logging event port link-status enable
```